# Insert com Foreign Key (usuario + endereco(FK)) PHP(PDO) + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde, galera.

Estou com uma pequena dúvida: Ao cadastrar um cliente (com um campo de endereço (fk)) a maneira correta é algo parecido com isso, ou tem uma maneira melhor?

```
INSERT INTO endereco(logradouro, numero, bairro, cidade)
VALUES (:logradouro, :numero, :bairro, :cidade)");
```

Pegar o ID onde o endereço coincida com o que foi inserido anteriormente;

```
SELECT id FROM endereco
WHERE logradouro = :logradouro AND numero = :numero 
                 AND bairro = :bairro AND cidade = :cidade;
```

Inserir o ID recuperado no SELECT no FK(id_do_select);

```
INSERT INTO usuario(login, senha, nome, endereco_id)
VALUES (:login, :senha, :nome, :id_do_select)");
```

Tem alguma maneira de inserir o id do endereço no FK do cliente sem antes fazer um SELECT?

vlw.

Comment: O endereço tem chave primaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando  o php PDO
use  o **$db->lastInsertId();**

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO 
endereco(logradouro, numero, bairro, cidade)
VALUES (:logradouro, :numero, :bairro, :cidade)';

$sql = $db->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute(array(valores-vao-aqui));

$id = $db->lastInsertId(); //retorna  ultimo  id inserido
```

Ou pelo  SQL

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2,...) VALUES ('val1', 'val2'...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Veja como funciona está função  em 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo! Muito obrigado.